# Problema con "return 1" en programa Caesar de CS50

Tags: c

Soy nueva en este mundo. Empecé el curso de CS50 y voy por la 2da semana en la que nos piden hacer un programa que encripte código, llamado Caesar.

Más o menos vengo ¨bien¨, pero uno de los requisitos es que se usen argumentos en la línea de comandos, y si no es exactamente lo que se necesita para generar el cifrado, debe salir un error y volverse a pedir el input.

Este es un pedacito de lo que tengo y donde me da problema.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) 
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n./caesar ");
        return 1;
    }
```

Si argc es igual a 2, perfecto, el programa sigue como debe; pero cuando es distinto de 2, imprime la leyenda, pero el "return 1" me finaliza completamente el programa, en vez de mandarme de nuevo a la línea de comandos para que vuelva a escribir otro input (que es lo que quiero).

HELP! :P

Comment: La función `main` por así decirlo es el principio de todo. Como puede observar es una función como otra cualquiera (aunque algo especial). Bien, teniendo claro que es una función, si pones la instrucción  `return` lo que va a pasar es que (en este caso `main`), dicha función va a salir y retornar un valor entero porque está definida como `int main` ( `1` en tu caso). No sé qué esperabas que pasase. Intenta explicar mejor lo que quieres conseguir y trataremos de ayudarte ;)

Comment: Gracias! Lo que necesito (y lo loco es que en alguna prueba me salió, pero no logro repetirlo), es que una vez que compruebe que el if es verdadero (argc distinto de 2), devuelva la leyenda "Usage..." y me pida un nuevo argumento, como cuando le puse en la línea de comandos, pero sin salir del programa, se puede?

Comment: No queda claro lo que quieres. Si desde una consola ejecutas tu programa y el argc es distinto de 2, el programa termina y sigues en la consola y podrás volver a ejecutar pasándole los parámetros correctos. Puedes mostrar el mensaje diciendo que lo han ejecutado mal y que tienen que pasar los parámetros que sean. Si lo que quieres es que no termine el programa, en vez de el return, tendrás que pedir por consola que introduzca el o los parámetros que necesites, y continuar con tu ejecución.